# Number values for dates wrong in excel?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, vba

I'm working on a project in excel and have run into an issue where when I'm displaying a date as a number in excel the number is wrong.

For example today (13/04/2018) should be number code `43203` but instead in the workbook I'm working on it is `41741`. I'm not sure what could be causing this issue. my date on my PC is set to dd/MM/yyyy as well as all the date formatted cells on my worksheet.
I am using the "=Now()" function to display the date as a number.

Comment: Is you date set on 1904 not 1900 in the settings for Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long long time ago, [Lotus 1-2-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_1-2-3) developers have decided to save a few bytes in their spreadsheet application. To make Excel compatible with Lotus, the Excel developers have introduced the same "mistake" within Excel. Thus, now you are facing the consequences of this action.

To solve it, go to `File > Options > Advanced` and uncheck:

**Use 1904 date system**:

[image]

[MSDN 1904 Date System](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214330/differences-between-the-1900-and-the-1904-date-system-in-excel)

This is how [Joel (SO co-founder)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky) describes his first encounter with the `1904` problem:
https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/06/16/my-first-billg-review/

Comment: That was it! Had no idea that this was an option in Excel. Thanks, for the explanation too its actually pretty interesting that they did that.

Comment: @NickHallick - you are welcome.